# Responsive image tag with wide color gamut support

Tags: html, image, responsive

I'm creating a web gallery of picture taken with the iPhone. They are in wide color gamut.

At this moment I use this HTML tag to handle responsive image.

```
<picture> <source media=”(min-width: 900px)”   srcset=“image-lg_1x.webp 1x, image-lg_2x.webp 2x”   type=“image/webp” > <source   media=”(min-width: 601px)”   srcset=“image-md_1x.webp 1x, image-md_2x.webp 2x”   type=“image/webp” > <source   srcset=“image-sm_1x.webp 1x, image-sm_2x.webp 2x”   type=“image/webp” > <img    srcset=“image-sm_1x.jpg 600w,   image-md_1x.jpg 900w,   image-lg_1x.jpg 1440w”   src=“image_lg_1x.jpg”   type=“image/jpeg”   alt=”image description”></picture>
```

I need to add the wide-color tag, and according to the guide the syntax is:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(color-gamut: p3)" srcset="photo-wide.jpg">
  <img src="photo-srgb.jpg">
</picture>
```

How can I mix them together?